# SSIS Conditional Split Decimals

Tags: ssis

I have a database table which contains column SLA Breach. This column (int) is composed from the numbers only (e.g. 25, 70, 30, ...) expressing hours.

In SSIS I have an conditional split in the format **"SLA Breach / 8 < 2"**
meaning divide the SLA Breach row number by 8 and set the condition. Based on several conditions I create the derived columns afterwards.

The conditions are as this:

> > ISNULL(SLA_Breach)
> >     SLA_Breach / 8 <= 2
> >     SLA_Breach > 2 && SLA_Breach / 8 <= 5
> >     SLA_Breach > 5 && SLA_Breach / 8 <= 10
> >     SLA_Breach / 8 > 10

For each conditions there is a derived column to only assign an ID (9, 1, 2, 3, 4) based on the condition.

**The example:**
The SLA Breach is 23. Based on the condition (23/8) is the result 2,875, so the third condition should apply and the ID 2 should be assigned to derived column. However, in DB table there is ID 1 assigned to this row (second condition) as it does not take the decimals into account.
The other example with SLA Breach being 24 works OK. 24/8 is 3 so the third condition is applied and the correct ID is assigned.

So the problem is not SSIS does not take the decimals into account. How this could be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the result of  SLA_Breach / 8  into derived column of decimal type, then do condition check.

```
decSLA_Breach = (DT_DECIMAL,2) SLA_Breach / 8
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I have put it like "((DT_DECIMAL,2)SLA_Breach / 8) <= 2" and it works OK ..